# Detailed official changelog for android versions

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, changelog

Is there any official changelog for the Android OS versions? We've realized some significant changes between 4.4.2 and 4.4.3 regarding the HLS stream implementation, so it would be really helpful to read about them, instead of guessing.
If there isn't any official changelog at this level, can it be somehow generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any official AOSP changelogs, but we can make a partial one out of the git history.

See this page: https://funkyandroid.com/aosp-changelogs.html